# How to create and view relation in yii framework for states and cities

Tags: php, yii, relation

I am a begginner in the `yii` framework and I can't find how to show relation in view.

I tried this way:

```
my model (Cities.php)
    public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'states' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'state_id')
            );
        }
```

My View Code is as below :

```
<?php 
    $cities = Cities::model()->findAll(); 
    foreach($cities as $city){
        $state=States::model()->findByPk($city->id);?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo cities.state_id;?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

But I am getting `error undefined index cities`. How can I fix that error?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? I think there is something wrong with your logic, cities are inside state, right ?
Can you post your db structure ?

Comment: I have two fields in states table : id and state_name. and other table is cities with three fields id, state_id and city. I want to show corresponding state name with city in my view.

Comment: so, you want to `echo` the `state_name` of the cities, right?

Comment: yes........................... :)

Comment: That day it was working but don't know where i did something wrong.. and now I am getting 'Trying to get property of non-object' error with same code.. :(

Comment: Can you post your code on pastebin and share the link?

Comment: I have n't changed anythig in my code.. my co-worker changed something in yii bat file.. is this the problem?

Comment: check your `cities` table, I guess one or more of the city are missing `state_id`.

Comment: state_id was not missing.. I truncate the table and inserted values again .. It is working now.. But I didn't understand what was the problem.. It may occur again.

Comment: Strange, I will have to look at the database then.

Comment: Its happening again.. what you need to check in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
<?php
$cities = Cities::model()->findAll();
foreach($cities as $city) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $city->states->state_name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The model:

```
public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'states' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'state_id')
            );
        }
```

Here,

`states` is the relationship name

`BELONGS_TO` is the relationship type

`State` is the model it is being connected to

`state_id` is the foreign key

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code as below :

```
<?php echo $city.state_id;?></td>
```

I have replaced `cities.state_id` to `$city.state_id` two mistakes as below

1. Your are looping on `$cities` and your variable `$city` is single object.
2. Typo mistake `echo cities.state_id` as here you have suppose to use $city and also you are not adding `$` name for variable.

EDIT after reading your comment:
Now if you want to show the state name using relation you can do it as below :

```
<?php echo $city->states->state_name; ?>
```

where `states` is a relationship name